# Where does Jensen's Inequality come into the EM derivation?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization

I am working my way through the original EM paper *Maximum Likelihood from Incomplete Data* by Dempster, et al.

I have run into a problem with a statement made in section 3. "General Properties". Specifically I am having a difficult time with Lemma 1:

[image]

My understanding of Jensen's inequality is

$$
\mathop{E}[f(X)] \geq f(\mathop{E}[X]) \text{ for convex functions } f(x)
$$

or the reverse for concave functions (e.g. the log of a pdf).

If I am interpreting equation $3.3$ correctly, we have

$$
\mathop{E}[\log k(x|y, \phi')|y, \phi] \leq \mathop{E}[\log k(x|y, \phi)|y, \phi] \\
\implies \int_X \log k(x|y, \phi') p(x | y, \phi) dx \leq \int_X \log k(x|y, \phi) p(x | y, \phi) dx
$$

I am failing to see where Jensen's inequality is applied as both sides of the equation include the function $\log k(\cdot)$ inside of the expectation.

Am I misunderstanding the application of Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the proof provided in McLachlan & Krishnan (1997) - *The EM Algorithm and Extensions* (converted to use the same notation as DLR):

$$
\begin{align}
H(\phi' \mid \phi) - H(\phi \mid \phi) & = E[\log k(x \mid y, \phi') \mid y, \phi] - E[\log k(x \mid y, \phi) \mid y, \phi] \\
& = E[\log \{k(x \mid y, \phi') / k(x \mid y, \phi) \} \mid y, \phi] \\
& \leq \log \{ E[k(x \mid y, \phi') / k(x \mid y, \phi) \mid y, \phi] \} \\
& = \log \int_{\mathcal{X}(y)} k(x \mid y, \phi') dx \\
& = 0
\end{align}
$$

Jensen's inequality is used in moving from the second to the third lines.