# Jensen's inequality in EM derivation: expectation derivation

Tags: conditional-expectation, expectation-maximization

In [Where does Jensen's Inequality come into the EM derivation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418686/where-does-jensens-inequality-come-into-the-em-derivation) and in  McLachlan & Krishnan (1997) - The EM Algorithm and Extensions, it was shown that

\begin{equation}
H(\theta|\theta^{(t)}) \leq H(\theta^{(t)} | \theta^{(t)} ) 
\end{equation}
by Jensen's inequality.
\begin{align}
H(\phi' \mid \phi) - H(\phi \mid \phi) & = E[\log k(x \mid y, \phi') \mid y, \phi] - E[\log k(x \mid y, \phi) \mid y, \phi] \\
& = E[\log \{k(x \mid y, \phi') / k(x \mid y, \phi) \} \mid y, \phi] \\
& \leq \log \{ E_{\phi}[k(x \mid y, \phi') / k(x \mid y, \phi) \mid y, \phi] \} \\
& = \log \int_{\mathcal{X}(y)} k(x \mid y, \phi') dx \\
& = 0
\end{align}

I am having difficulty understanding how we go from the 3rd to 4th equality. I tried taking out $K(x \mid y, \phi)$, ie:
\begin{align}
\log \{ E_{\phi}[k(x \mid y, \phi') / k(x \mid y, \phi) \mid y, \phi] \}  
&= \log \{ \frac{1}{K(x \mid y, \phi)}E_{\phi}[k(x \mid y, \phi')  \mid y, \phi] \} \\ 
\end{align}
and also have difficulty how we went from taking expectation with respect to $\phi$ to integrating over $\mathcal{X}(y)$.

Apologize if this is a fundamental question.

Comment: Jensen's inequality implies that $\log\{\mathbb E[Z]\}\le\{\mathbb E[\log Z]\}$ whatever the (positive) random variable $Z$ and explains the move from second to third row in the equation.

Answer (score 2):

The expectation $E_{\phi}\left [\frac{k(X \mid y, \phi')}{ k(X \mid y, \phi)} \Big| y, \phi \right ] $ is taken with respect to $x$ when $X \sim k(x \mid y, \phi)$

Thus,

\begin{align*}
E_{\phi}\left [\frac{k(X \mid y, \phi')}{ k(X \mid y, \phi)} \Big| y, \phi \right ] &= \int_{{\mathcal{X}(y)}} \frac{k(x \mid y, \phi')}{ k(x \mid y, \phi)} k(x \mid y, \phi) dx \\
&= \int_{{\mathcal{X}(y)}} k(x \mid y, \phi') dx \\
&= 1
\end{align*}

For the notation ${\mathcal{X}(y)}$ my guess is that it is used to emphasize that we are integrating over the distribution of $X \mid Y=y$ and the support of this distribution may depend on $y$